Reusable FormControl component implementing ControlValueAccessor
I am attempting to create a reusable custom-input component that does not have the formControlName hard coded anywhere in the custom-input component (I have found some examples where the formControlName is hardcoded in the custom component). I want to be able to supply only the formControlName to the component, so that the same component could be used for multiple FormControls  within one FormGroup.
Here is a Stackblitz, and the relevant code is below:
/// CustomInputComponent ///
import { Component, forwardRef, Input, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule, ControlValueAccessor, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, NG_VALIDATORS } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  standalone: true,
  selector: 'custom-input',
  template: `  <input
                  class="input"
                  type="text"
                  [disabled]="disabled"
                  (input)="updateValue($event)"
                  [value]="value"
                />`,
  styles: [],
  imports: [CommonModule, FormsModule],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      multi: true,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => CustomInputComponent),
    },
    {
      provide: NG_VALIDATORS,
      multi: true,
      useExisting: CustomInputComponent,
    },
  ],
})
export class CustomInputComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {  
  @ViewChild('input', { static: true }) input!: ElementRef<HTMLInputElement>;

  @Input() ctrlConfigData!: any;
  @Input() ctrlName!: string;

  @Input() value = '';
  disabled: boolean = false;

  onChanged: any = () => {};
  onTouched: any = () => {};

  writeValue(value: string): void {  // Update component state
    console.log('writeValue() called with:', value);
    this.value = value;
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: any): void { // Register the callback for value changes
    this.onChanged = fn;
  }

  registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
    this.onTouched = fn;
  }

  setDisabledState(isDisabled: boolean): void {
    this.disabled = isDisabled;
  }

  updateValue(event: Event): void {
    const newValue = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).value;
    console.log('newValue: ' + newValue);
    this.value = newValue;
    this.onChanged(newValue);
    this.onTouched();
  }

}


Here is the parent component, which creates the FormGroup and instantiates the custom component:
/// ContainerComponent ///
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { CustomInputComponent } from '../custom-input/custom-input.component';


@Component({
  standalone: true,
  selector: 'container',
  template: `
      <custom-input 
        formControlName="ctrlA" 
      </custom-input>
`,
  styles: [],
  imports: [CommonModule, CustomInputComponent],
})
export class ContainerComponent implements OnInit{
  fg: FormGroup = new FormGroup({});
  
  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('ContainerComponent instantiated');
  
    this.fg.addControl('ctrlA', 
    new FormControl({ disabled: false, value: 'ctrlA!!' }));
    this.fg.addControl('ctrlB', 
    new FormControl({ disabled: false, value: 'ctrlB' }));
  }


}

Thanks.

What is the issue?

You have to import ReactiveFormsModule to the component, to use the formGroup directive.
@Component({
  standalone: true,
  selector: 'container',
  templateUrl: './container.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./container.component.scss'],
  imports: [CommonModule, CustomInputComponent, ReactiveFormsModule],
})

Then make sure you wrap the custom inputs in a formGroup directive.
<form [formGroup]="fg">
  <custom-input
    formControlName="ctrlA"
    [ctrlConfigData]="{ label: 'CTRL A' }"
    [ctrlName]="'ctrlA'"
  >
  </custom-input>
  <custom-input
    formControlName="ctrlB"
    [ctrlConfigData]="{ label: 'CTRL B' }"
    [ctrlName]="'ctrlB'"
  ></custom-input>
</form>

Finally, I removed the validators providers property, since it's only needed when you provide custom validators.
providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      multi: true,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => CustomInputComponent),
    },
    // {
    //   provide: NG_VALIDATORS,
    //   multi: true,
    //   useExisting: CustomInputComponent,
    // },
  ],
})

FULL CODE:
Custom Input:
import {
  Component,
  forwardRef,
  Input,
  ViewChild,
  ElementRef,
} from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import {
  FormsModule,
  ControlValueAccessor,
  NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
  NG_VALIDATORS,
} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  standalone: true,
  selector: 'custom-input',
  template: `  <input
                  class="input"
                  type="text"
                  (focus)="onTouched()"
                  [disabled]="disabled"
                  (input)="updateValue($event)"
                  [value]="value"
                />`,
  // templateUrl: './custom-input.component.html',
  styles: [],
  imports: [CommonModule, FormsModule],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      multi: true,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => CustomInputComponent),
    },
    // {
    //   provide: NG_VALIDATORS,
    //   multi: true,
    //   useExisting: CustomInputComponent,
    // },
  ],
})
export class CustomInputComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {
  @ViewChild('input', { static: true }) input!: ElementRef<HTMLInputElement>;

  @Input() ctrlConfigData!: any;
  @Input() ctrlName!: string;

  @Input() value = '';
  disabled: boolean = false;

  onChanged: any = () => {};
  onTouched: any = () => {};

  writeValue(value: string): void {
    // Update component state
    console.log('writeValue() called with:', value);
    this.value = value;
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
    // Register the callback for value changes
    this.onChanged = fn;
  }

  registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
    this.onTouched = fn;
  }

  setDisabledState(isDisabled: boolean): void {
    this.disabled = isDisabled;
  }

  updateValue(event: Event): void {
    const newValue = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).value;
    console.log('newValue: ' + newValue);
    this.value = newValue;
    this.onChanged(newValue);
    this.onTouched();
  }
}

Parent HTML:
<form [formGroup]="fg">
  <custom-input
    formControlName="ctrlA"
    [ctrlConfigData]="{ label: 'CTRL A' }"
    [ctrlName]="'ctrlA'"
  >
  </custom-input>
  <custom-input
    formControlName="ctrlB"
    [ctrlConfigData]="{ label: 'CTRL B' }"
    [ctrlName]="'ctrlB'"
  ></custom-input>
</form>
<!-- reset button -->
<div style="margin: 4rem 0 0 0"><button>Reset Form</button></div>

<!-- monitoring values -->
<div style="padding-top:1rem;">
  <table border="1">
    <tr>
      <th style="padding: 10px">FormControl (ctrlA)</th>
      <th style="padding: 10px">FormControl (ctrlB)</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="padding: 10px">
        touched : {{ fg.get('ctrlA')?.touched }} <br />
        dirty : {{ fg.get('ctrlA')?.dirty }} <br />
        valid : {{ fg.get('ctrlA')?.valid }} <br />
        Value : {{ fg.get('ctrlA')?.value }} <br />
        Required : {{ fg.get('ctrlA')?.hasError('required') }}
      </td>
      <td style="padding: 10px">
        touched : {{ fg.get('ctrlB')?.touched }} <br />
        dirty : {{ fg.get('ctrlB')?.dirty }} <br />
        valid : {{ fg.get('ctrlB')?.valid }} <br />
        Value : {{ fg.get('ctrlB')?.value }} <br />
        Required : {{ fg.get('ctrlB')?.hasError('required') }}
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

Parent TS:
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { CustomInputComponent } from '../custom-input/custom-input.component';

@Component({
  standalone: true,
  selector: 'container',
  templateUrl: './container.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./container.component.scss'],
  imports: [CommonModule, CustomInputComponent, ReactiveFormsModule],
})
export class ContainerComponent implements OnInit {
  fg: FormGroup = new FormGroup({});

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('ContainerComponent instantiated');

    this.fg.addControl(
      'ctrlA',
      new FormControl({ disabled: false, value: 'ctrlA!!' })
    );
    this.fg.addControl(
      'ctrlB',
      new FormControl({ disabled: false, value: 'ctrlB' })
    );
  }

  resestForm() {
    this.fg?.get('ctrlA')?.setValue('ctrlA reset!');
    this.fg?.get('ctrlB')?.setValue('ctrlB reset!');
  }
}

Stackblitz Demo

Thanks for the explicit recommendations! Looks like I was missing a few key steps - this is working now.
